# Batching singleemailmessage

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I would like to schedule an email to send out everyday at 8am to all contacts that meet the requirements:

> account_expiration__c != null

I wrote a schedulable apex class but i reach [singleEmailMessage limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm). (Provided below)

I looked into using the [massEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm) class, but cannot impliment as i need the email to come from a specific user based on ownership and there is no *setOrgWideEmailAddressId()* method. So my conclusion is i cannot utilize this class.

I then thought that i may be able to utilize a [batch class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm?search_text=Batch), but i really cant find any example of anyone using it for something other then to iterate through sObjects.

My question is: is there any way that i haven’t explored to accomplish my goal? Maybe an easier way. (Im a novice and tend to take the hard way)

or

Am i on the correct path using a batchable class? And if so can someone please show me an example of how one would batch *singleEmailMessage*?

```
global class dailyEmail implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

    //querying all approved Contacts
    list<Account> lstApprovedAcct = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Account_Status__c = 'Approved'];
    list<Contact> lstApprovedCon = [SELECT ID, Owner.Email FROM Contact WHERE HasOptedOutOfEmail = false AND Email != null AND Contact.AccountID IN :lstApprovedAcct];

    //getting org wide email address which is used in template email as whom it will be sending to. 
    OrgWideEmailAddress lorin = [SELECT ID, Address FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE Address = 'lleonard@unitedmortgage.com' LIMIT 1];
    OrgWideEmailAddress jason = [SELECT ID, Address FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE Address = 'jfrangoulis@unitedmortgage.com' LIMIT 1];

    // select email template    
    EmailTemplate lorinTemplate = [SELECT Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Daily Email - Lorin' limit 1];
    EmailTemplate jasonTemplate = [SELECT Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Daily Email - Jason' limit 1];

    //List of Emails to be sent, after iteration of orgWideIDs are added as individuals.
    list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstEmailJason = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    //Lorin list of emails to send
    list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstEmailLorin = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    //loop through each contact and send a single templated message
    for(Contact iterator : lstApprovedCon) {
        if(iterator.owner.Email == jason.Address) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage jayMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            jayMail.setTargetObjectId(iterator.Id); //contact ID
            jayMail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(jason.ID); // from address
            jayMail.setTemplateId(jasonTemplate.Id); //template ID
            jayMail.setUseSignature(false);
            lstEmailJason.add(jayMail);
        }   
        else if (iterator.owner.Email == lorin.Address) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage lorinMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            lorinMail.setTargetObjectId(iterator.Id); //contact ID
            lorinMail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(lorin.ID); // from address
            lorinMail.setTemplateId(lorinTemplate.Id); //template ID
            LorinMail.setUseSignature(false);
            lstEmailLorin.add(lorinMail);
        }
    }
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
        if(!lstEmailLorin.isEmpty()) 
            Messaging.sendEmail(lstEmailLorin); 
        if(!lstEmailJason.isEmpty()) 
            Messaging.sendEmail(lstEmailJason);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A batch class is not going to change your email limit consumption, which is a daily total - it doesn't matter how you use it up. If you're sending more than 5,000 single or bulk messages per day and Salesforce is not willing to increase the limit for you, you'll need to look at integrating a bulk email application with Salesforce.

EDIT: Based upon discussion in comments, your class is not failing due to a limits error at all, but due to bad/bouncing email addresses. You may want to [set allOrNothing to false](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm#apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging) in addition to addressing your data issues.

Comment: It doesnt reach salesforce mass email limits at all, in total there are 238 in use. If you follow the link it reaches singlememailmessage class limits of 100 addresses in the TO field per instance.

Comment: Please add the complete text of the error message you receive in your question, along with the line number where the error is thrown.

Comment: No error message at all, its scheduled and works in sandbox but not in production. There are only 10 contacts that meet the requirements in sandbox and 238 in production, i found the limits page after i rolled out. Should i add a try catch?

Comment: If you are not receiving an error message, it is hard to diagnose the issue. I do not believe that you are hitting the To address limit, because you are not adding multiple To addresses to any single message. You'll need to review your logs and email delivery settings to help determine what class of error you're dealing with.

Comment: Im not sure how to find any error? I added a debug log for the class and rescheduled it. As the code is written now do i have to add debug stements?

Comment: When you look up the job under Apex Jobs in Setup, what do you see after it runs?

Comment: i have unscheduled it previously, so i rescheduled it but it hasnt fired yet. i will bump up the schedule since it doesnt send anyway. let you know the results. thank you.

Comment: "Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: jobId: 7071a00003ty74O, class: common.apex.async.AsyncApexJobObject, reason: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 4; first error: EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED, The target object email address is currently marked..."

Comment: so its all because of a bounce? how can i stop bounced email addresses from entering the program?

Comment: There is a boolean field on contact called IsEmailBounced. If you filter those out in your query you should be good to go. By the way, those are only a specific subset of bounces in my experience. My limited personal experience is that it's like maybe 10 percent of the actual bounces.

Comment: @Kasper im not sure what you mean? Wht does a specific subset mean?

Comment: @BryanCerrati Salesforce has the option for bounce management (see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=5 ). In my experience about ten percent of the bounces are handled by Salesforce, and in those cases the IsEmailBounced becomes true. All the other bounces end up in the senders email inbox. However, I've never looked into this so this may just be a setting mistake in our org or at the email provider that causes only 10 percent to be captured by Salesforce. At any rate, if limit your contact query to IsEmailBounced = false, than your code should work.

Comment: @Kasper great idea, and you are correct alot of users that recieve a bounce report do end up recieveing the email in their inbox. Im going to test both allOrNothing, and filtering in the soql query isEmailBounced. I will let you know the results monday morning.

Comment: @DavidReed used allOrNothing. Worked.